# Measure L1 data cache miss with perf and papi

Tags: c++, performance, caching, perf, papi

What is the difference between `PAPI_L1_LDM` in papi and `L1-dcache-load-misses` in perf?

I've used the same setting, like [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39709328/why-does-perf-and-papi-give-different-values-for-l3-cache-references-and-misses).

So, as a result I get for papi:

```
PAPI_L1_DCM: 515 <- L1 data cache miss (probably L1D_READ_MISSES_ALL + L1D_READ_MISSES_RETRIED?)
PAPI_L1_ICM: 300 <- L1 Instruction cache miss
PAPI_L1_LDM: 441 <- L1 Load data miss
PAPI_L1_TCM: 815 <- L1 Total cache miss
```

Unfortunately `PAPI_L1_DCA` is not supported at this machine.

And for perf (only in the user-space, since papi measures also only user-space and no kernel space):
call: `perf stat -B -e L1-dcache-load-misses:u,cache-misses:u ./perf`

```
    16,539      L1-dcache-load-misses
       128      cache-misses:u
```

16,539 seems to be more reasonable for `N=1000000`. What is the difference between a load-data-miss (PAPI_L1_LDM in papi) and a data cache miss (PAPI_L1_DCM in papi) and why do these numbers differ in papi and perf? Is the `cache-misses:u` in perf related to the L2 cache-misses?

edit: Hardware (Xeon E5-2600 v3 family, Haswell-EP 12 cores)

Comment: Now I go with Vtune, since the GUI gives you also a command-line snippet.